# How to wait for disposal of Flux in Reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am working with a Reactor Flux in Spring Webflux.
I would like to wait for the completion of the Flux (filling a list) while finishing some other stuff in parallel. Now my question is, how can I wait for the completion without having to rely on `Thread.sleep` like this:

```
List<MyObject> results = new ArrayList<>();
Disposable disposable = myFlux.subscribe(results::add);

//do some other stuff

//now wait for the flux to finish
while(!disposable.isDisposed()) {
  Thread.sleep(500L);
}

return results;
```

Comment: you can try use the operator ```publish``` in multiple thread model , you usage may  cause lot of  idle cpu time , and  lost the reactive programing meaning

Comment: or else  you can read the javadoc  juc package  ,  ```CountDownLatch``` may be  suitable for your scenario

Comment: To keep advantages of Reactor scheduling/reactive model, it would be better to try to keep working with FLux/Mono objects. You could, for example, use `myFlux.collectList().zipWith(otherOperationProducingMono)`.

Comment: Can't you get rid of the list as you have it now, and simply return `myFlux.collectList().block()`? You can split that in two statements if needed: `Mono<List<MyObject>> resultsMono = myFlux.collectList()`, do other stuff, return `resultsMono.block()`.

Comment: Your proposed solution answers your direct question. But you'd never do and never need that with a real code, so I suggest to rephrase the question to explain what you really want to do in your code.

Comment: I think @RobSpoor's suggestion is what I was after. I wasn't aware that you could split the statement like that. Thanks for pointing that out. Obviously ```Thread.sleep``` and active waiting was never a good solution.